# want to create a database for my incoming messages

Tags: android, database

I want to create a database which will store the messages according to the phone numbers.
How can i do it?
I am able to create a simple database which will store the messages as a stack means it will not arrange the messages according to numbers.
for a simple database, i am using this code,

```
mydb =  openOrCreateDatabase("db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);                              
        mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sms_inbox (SMS_TEXT varchar , SENDER_NUMBER varchar );");      

        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO sms_inbox VALUES('" + stBody + "', '" + stPhoneNumber + "');");
```

now how will I be able to store these messages according to the Phone Numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite3 might be a good choice for you.  It's an in-memory, embeddable relational database.

Create a database; add a table with a primary key id, phone number, time stamp, and message text.  You can SELECT and ORDER BY phone number.  Off you go!

Comment: Means i have to create a table named as KEY_ID and then store the messages of a specific number and then if again the message comes from a different number then  again i will have to create a table for that particular no.means KEY_ID2..

Comment: No, all the numbers in one table.  You need to understand how relational databases work.  Your comment suggests to me that you don't.  I'm assuming that the database is associated with one phone, one user.  If not, I'd have another table that would contain recipient user id and phone number with a one-to-many relationship with a message table.

Comment: no,i do not know about relational databases. will be please help me regarding this problem in some elaborated method..

Comment: Nope, it's your time to go read and learn.  I already did help you.  Create one table with four columns.  See if you can do that.

Comment: Voted up. Perfect answer...!